# node.js process suppress output but not input

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, stream, spawn

I have this code:

```
var convert = spawn("gm", ["convert"].concat(parameters));
// output stream
obj.outStream = new BufferList();

convert.stderr.pipe(process.stderr, { end: false });
// put the output in the stream TOO
convert.stdout.pipe(obj.outStream);
// send the image to the input
obj.stream.pipe(throttle).pipe(convert.stdin);
```

How can I suppress the output of the "convert" process, without suppressing the input and the output to obj.outStream too?

The reason is because I don't want to output that to the user, as it does now.

Comment: Could you clarify what you actually mean? You say you want to suppress output without suppressing output and don't want output and that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: sorry. I meant that if you open the console, with this code, you see the image converted (that is the output of the gm command). I don't want that.

However I want the image's stream in the obj.outStream to work with it before returning it to the user.

Comment: So you're saying `convert.stdout.pipe(obj.outStream);` pipes the output, but it still shows in console? Is there a possibility that the application pipes to `stderr` instead?

Comment: yes, exactly. There's also stderr, but it's correctly handled in another part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably seeing in the output is `convert.stderr` because you are piping it to `process.stderr`, which is the error output of your child process' master. When you spawn a child process, by default, no `stdio` is handled.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn'
var child = spawn('gm', ['convert']);
```

The code that you've shown is that you're directly piping the child's `stderr` to the main process' `stderr` and piping `stdout` to your `outStream`. That means the only possible output you can see is `convert.stderr`.

To fix this, ignore `stderr`.

```
var obj = {
  outStream: new BufferList()
};

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn'
var child = spawn('gm', ['convert'], {
  stdio: ['pipe', obj.outStream, 'ignore']
});
```

With this, you have the `stdin` stream as it normally is, `stdout` piped to `obj.outStream`m and `stderr` ignored.

Comment: the problem was actually not the err but the fact that I pipe the result in another part of the code to the std.out (and it was a lot below in the code). Unfortunately it's not something that I wrote, but it's something I have to maintain.

However, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stderr) you can use listeners or use the 'ignore' property.

Comment: I've tried with the ignore, but it will affect both the terminal output and the output to the variable (at least, how I used it).